# How to increase the value of a quantity field with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form with some quantity field and a plus and minus sign on each side,

```
    <form id="myform">
        product1
        <input type="submit" value="+" id="add">
        <input type="text" id="qty1">
        <input type="submit value="-" id="minus">
        product2
        <input type="submit" value="+" id="add">
        <input type="text" id="qty2">
        <input type="submit value="-" id="minus">
    </form>
```

I'd like to increase the value of the field by one if the add
button is pressed and decrease by one if minus is pressed.
Also the value shouldn't get less than 0.

Is there a way to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, `type="submit"` should be `type="button"` in all cases. Also, you cannot have two elements with the same ID; I assume you want `add1`, `minus1`, `add2`, `minus2`, etc.

The following jQuery code should work great.

```
$(function () {
    var numButtons = 10;
    for (var i = 1; i <= numButtons; ++i) {
        $("#add" + i).click(function () {
            var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + i).val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                $("#qty" + i).val(currentVal + 1);
            }
        });

        $("#minus" + i).click(function () {
            var currentVal = parseInt($("qty" + i).val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                $("#qty" + i).val(currentVal - 1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Worth noting:

- I wrap everything in a `$(function() { ... })` call so that you attach the event handlers only after the page loads. (Specifically, after the `DomContentLoaded` event.) This prevents errors about how an object with the ID "add1" doesn't exist or whatever, because technically that object doesn't exist until the page actually loads.
- Checks for `NaN` handles the case of the user typing non-numeric stuff into the field. You could add your own logic for that in particular, e.g. auto-convert non-numeric properties to 0 whenever someone clicks add or minus.

Comment: Yeah, that's a better and safer version of what I was doing :)

Comment: how can I generalize this to multiple fields if they all have unique ids, should I change the #add1 to sth else

Comment: I updated my answer to work on an arbitrary number of fields, assuming you name them qtyX/addX/minusX, where X is a number between 1 and `numButtons` inclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Your html isn't quite valid, you have multiple elements with the same id, it should be unique. But lets say you only had one set of inputs/buttons:

```
$("#add").click(function(){
  var newQty = +($("#qty1").val()) + 1;
  $("#qty1").val(newQty);
});

$("#minus").click(function(){
  var newQty = +($("#qty1").val()) - 1;
  if(newQty < 0)newQty = 0;
  $("#qty1").val(newQty);
});
```

Comment: hi, I have like 10 plus and minus buttons, do I have to write the same code for every single plus and minus button or is there a way to just write it once.
thanks

Comment: Ah ok, then Domenic's answer should sort you out, just need to apply these click handlers in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a rookie, but I did it like this for integers...

```
<div class="quantityInput" min="-32" max="32">
    <input type="text" class="quantityText">
    <input type="button" value="+" class="quantityPlus">
    <input type="button" value="-" class="quantityMinus">
</div>
```

min and max attributes are optional.  Then, inside jQuery(document).ready(...

```
$(".quantityMinus").live("click", function() {
  var qInput = $(this).parents(".quantityInput");
  var qText = qInput.find(".quantityText");
  var qValue = parseInt((qText.val())? qText.val() : 0);
  qText.val(Math.max(qValue - 1, (qInput.attr("min"))? qInput.attr("min") : -0xffff));
});

$(".quantityPlus").live("click", function() {
  var qInput = $(this).parents(".quantityInput");
  var qText = qInput.find(".quantityText");
  var qValue = parseInt((qText.val())? qText.val() : 0);
  qText.val(Math.min(qValue + 1, (qInput.attr("max"))? qInput.attr("max") : 0xffff));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **unique id's** for all your inputs, e.g. `qty1_add`, `qty1_minus`.
Then you can attach the click event to these buttons:

```
$("#qty1_add").click( function() {
   $("#qty1").val( parseInt($("#qty1").val()) + 1);
}).
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the improved response of the first aswer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    $(".add").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).next(".qty").val());
        if (currentVal != NaN)
        {
            $(this).next(".qty").val(currentVal + 1);
        } 
    });

    $(".minus").click(function()
    {
        var currentVal = parseInt($(this).prev(".qty").val());
        if (currentVal != NaN)
        {
            $(this).prev(".qty").val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="myform">
        product1
        <input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="add" />        
        <input type="text" id="qty1" value="-1" class="qty" />        
        <input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" /><br /><br />

        product2
        <input type="button" value="+" id="add2" class="add" />        
        <input type="text" id="qty2" value="-10" class="qty" />        
        <input type="button" value="-" id="minus2" class="minus" />

    </form>

</body>
```

I hope they serve.... :D

Answer (score 0):

First, at minus buttons, you need to have type="submit", not type="submit, but I assume that is typing mistake ;)

If you want to do that, you should change plus and minus button ids to something like 'minus-qty1', 'add-qty1', etc. to identify which input you'd like to update.

```
  <form id="myform">
    product1
    <input type="button" value="+" id="add-qty1" onclick="increase(this)">
    <input type="text" id="qty1">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="minus-qty1" onclick="decrease(this)">
    product2
    <input type="button" value="+" id="add-qty2" onclick="increase(this)">
    <input type="text" id="qty2">
    <input type="button" value="-" id="minus-qty2" onclick="decrease(this)">

  </form>

function increase(button)
{
 var id = $(button).attr('id');
 var fname = id.substr(3);

 var newval = parseInt($("#"+fname).val()) + 1;
 $("#" + fname).val(newval);
}


function decrease(button)
{
 var id = $(button).attr('id');
 var fname = id.substr(5);

 var newval = parseInt($("#"+fname).val()) - 1;
 $("#" + fname).val(newval);
}
```

I hope it works, I didn't try it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
$('#add').click(function (e) {
    var quant = $(this).next('input');
    quant.val(parseInt(quant.val(), 10) + 1);
};
$('#minus').click(function (e) {
    var quant = $(this).prev('input');
    quant.val(parseInt(quant.val(), 10) - 1);
    if (parseInt(quant.val(), 10) < 0)
    { quant.val(0); }
};
```

This does however depend on the relative positioning of the controls not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for everyone who got involved. All I drew upon and was able to come up with this in the end, that served the site very well (it was just the css that was a pain!)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="qtybox"><label for="qty">
<venda_text id=site.quantity>
</label><input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="1" size="3" maxlength="2"></input>
<button id="qtyplus" onclick="return false"></button>
    <button id="qtyminus" onclick="return false"></button>

</div>
```

**js:**

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#qtyplus").click(function(){     
     jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val( Number(jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    jQuery("#qtyminus").click(function(){
     if(jQuery('#qty').val()>1)
      jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val( Number(jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );

    });
  });
```

**CSS:**

```
#qtybox button#qtyplus {
    background: url("../images/social_icons/elements.png") no-repeat scroll -268px -223px   
    transparent;
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
}
```

As you can see, I removed the values of the +'s and -'s - hated how it was rendered!