# Jquery calculation

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery calculation to do a sum on one of my client pages. Simple calculation is working fine but I have to integrate an add and remove button with the input tags. As in instead of manually entering a number client wants to use add and remove button to increase and decrease the value of the product and eventually adding up to the totalSum.

Hoping someone can help me with this as I am not yet an expert in jquery. :)

Here the HTML code

```
<div class="amount">    
            <input type="text" class="count"  name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" size="2" readonly="readonly">                      </div>



    <div class="clearfix"></div><!--Please do not delete this div-->
    <!--Case 1-->       
    <div class="bottle_in_case">
                <div class="addRemove">
                <input type="text" value="2" class="count" maxlength="2" name="case" id="case_1"> bottles
                <p class="add_remove_btns"><a href="#"><img src="images/add.gif" alt=""> Add</a> / <a href="#"><img src="images/remove.gif" alt=""> Remove</a></p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!--Case 2-->       
    <div class="bottle_in_case">

        <div class="addRemove">
                <input type="text" value="2" class="count" maxlength="2" name="case" id="case_2"> bottles
                <p class="add_remove_btns"><a href="#"><img src="images/add.gif" alt=""> Add</a> / <a href="#"><img src="images/remove.gif" alt=""> Remove</a></p>
            </div>
    </div>

    <!--Case 3-->       
    <div class="bottle_in_case last">

            <div class="addRemove">
                <input type="text" value="2" class="count" maxlength="2" name="case" id="case_3"> bottles
                <p class="add_remove_btns"><a href="#"><img src="images/add.gif" alt=""> Add</a> / <a href="#"><img src="images/remove.gif" alt=""> Remove</a></p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

The Script I have used is

```
$("input[name^='case']").sum();
```

$("input[name^=case]").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");

Thanks in advance

Neha

Comment: Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: you want how to get the value using jquery??

Comment: I have been asked to use Jquery but if something simple in JavaScript can be a help then why not. Just that I am not very familiar with JS!

Comment: Look at this page here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211354/how-to-increase-the-value-of-a-quantity-field-with-jquery

Comment: I am using jquery.calculation at the moment to get a simple totalSum and it works fine but now I have to integrate this add and remove button with the input to increase and decrease the sum!

Comment: This question is way too broad. You should show some of the code you have at the very least

Comment: You say you have done some work already? If so, show us your code and we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: to attach a quantity changer to the add.gif and remove.gif:

```
<p class="add_remove_btns"><a href="#"><img src="images/add.gif" alt=""> Add</a> / <a href="#"><img src="images/remove.gif" alt=""> Remove</a>
```

Change all instances of above to

```
<p class="add_remove_btns"><a href="#" class="add_qty" rel="1"><img src="images/add.gif" alt=""> Add</a> / <a href="#" class="remove_qty" rel="1"><img src="images/remove.gif" alt=""> Remove</a>
```

Of course each instance of rel="1" or rel="2" would have to correspond with the id="case_1" 's numbers...

Now in the jQuery (running on document ready syntax)

```
$('add_qty').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('rel');
    var newqty = $('#case_'+target).val()+1;
    $('#case_'+target).val(newqty);
    recalculate_total();
    return false;
  });    
});

$('remove_qty').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('rel');
    var newqty = $('#case_'+target).val()-1;
    if(newqty<0) {newqty=0;} // qty cannot be below 0, so override to 0 if thats the case
    $('#case_'+target).val(newqty);
    recalculate_total();
    return false;
  });    
});
```

To get the sum of all the rows, create this function OUTSIDE the document ready syntax:

```
 function recalculate_total() {
    var total = 0;
    $('input.count').each(function(){
    total = total+$(this).val()*1;
    });
    $('#totalSum').val(total);
    }
```

Let me know if this works.. provide a URL for me too so I can troubleshoot if there is an error.

Comment: Also dont' forget to include a method to run the recalculate_total() somewher e- could be part of the click function I wrote on the last code box.

Comment: hey can you have a look on the code. I have edited it in the question. Sorry for bothering you. It would be great if you can have a look. Thanks

Comment: Ooops. OK I forgot the *1. var newqty = $('#case_'+target).val()+1; should be var newqty = $('#case_'+target).val()*1+1; and same goes for the remove function. Try that...

Comment: What's happening is, if you don't specify the value as an integer, it passes as a string, and 1+1 becomes 11, not 2. But multiplying a value by 1 (*1) is a sure way of turning a string number into a true integer number. works in PHP settings as well..

Comment: But the grand total is still not correct :((( .. have updated the page .. u can check again.. and when u subtract it still keeps on adding to the grand total!!

Comment: Try updating teh calculate_total() function with the edited function I just wrote. I put the bracket at the wrong place,i think.

Comment: No its not workings.. What it is doing is its adding the cases and then adding it to the previous grand total and displaying the new total.

Comment: AH! From the total sum field, take  class="count" out.

Comment: <input type="text" class="count"  name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" size="2" readonly="readonly"> should become <input type="text" name="totalSum" id="totalSum" value="" size="2" readonly="readonly">    cause my script counts all teh sums in all inputs with class="count"

Comment: YEAAAAA!!!!!! it works :) :) :) :) .. Now the only thing I need to do is make the intial grand total visible and not hidden :) .. Thank you sooooooooooo much :)

Comment: set the document so that upon document ready, it runs that recalculate_total() function.

Answer (score 1):

Simple calculation using jquery

```
    <table id="table" border="0">
        <thead>
            <th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Total</th>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input id ="price" type = "text"></input></td>
        <td><input id ="quantity" type = "text"></input></td>
        <td><input id ="total" type = "text"></input></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

<a href="#" id="calc">Calculate</a>
```

Jquery Function:

```
$(function(){
    $('a#calc').click(function(){
    var q = $('input#quantity').val();
    var p = $('input#price').val();
    var tot = (q*p);
    $('input#total').val(tot);
    });
 });
```

I hope its help to you

Comment: Hey thanks! .. I have used something similar to do the calculation from this website http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm#ex-calc