# Increase and decrease values for inputs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to increase and decrease the value of inputs when clicking the + and - buttons but it doesn't seem to work. I got the code from this post: [How to increase the value of a quantity field with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211354/how-to-increase-the-value-of-a-quantity-field-with-jquery) When clicking on the add button, I inserted a console.log statement for debugging purposes and surprisingly, I get a value of 3 even though I clicked on a button with an id of add1. Would really appreciate it if you could point out to me the error, thanks!

HTML:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20">
        <input id="qty1" type="text" value="1">
        <img id="add1" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20">
    </p>

    <p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus2" width="20" height="20">
        <input id="qty2" type="text" value="1">
        <img id="add2" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20">
    </p>
</body>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    var numButtons = 2;
    //console.log(typeof(numButtons));
    //console.log(numButtons);
    for (var i = 1; i <= numButtons; i++) {

        $("#add" + i).click(function () {
            console.log(i);
            var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + i).val());
            //console.log(currentVal);
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                $("#qty" + i).val(currentVal + 1);
            }
        });

        $("#minus" + i).click(function () {
            var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + i).val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                $("#qty" + i).val(currentVal - 1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hMS6Y/

Comment: why are you iterating over numButtons?  Why not just have event handlers?

Comment: Hmm, will take that into consideration. I have to generate multiple inputs with different ids, that's why I thought the for loop makes sense. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Your variable i is in a global state and when the for loop terminates its value becomes 3 and the functions you pass to click event access the value of i when they are triggered on click event. So the value of i these functions will get will be 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this in a simple way using `class`,

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus"/>
        <input id="qty1" type="text" value="1" class="qty"/>
            <img id="add1" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20" class="add"/>
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus2" width="20" height="20" class="minus"/>
        <input id="qty2" type="text" value="1" class="qty"/>
        <img id="add2" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20" class="add"/>
    </p>
</body>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(function () {
    $('.add').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
        }
    });
    $('.minus').on('click',function(){
        var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');
        var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
        }
    });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hMS6Y/2/

**Alternatively,** you can short your code like,

```js
$(function() {
  $('.minus,.add').on('click', function() {
    var $qty = $(this).closest('p').find('.qty'),
      currentVal = parseInt($qty.val()),
      isAdd = $(this).hasClass('add');
    !isNaN(currentVal) && $qty.val(
      isAdd ? ++currentVal : (currentVal > 0 ? --currentVal : currentVal)
    );
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus1" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <input id="qty1" type="text" value="1" class="qty" />
  <img id="add1" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />
</p>
<p>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" id="minus2" width="20" height="20" class="minus" />
  <input id="qty2" type="text" value="1" class="qty" />
  <img id="add2" src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" width="20" height="20" class="add" />
</p>
```

Comment: don't know why you were down-voted, but I definitely think a `class` solution is best.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to know why put a $ in front of qty in this statement var $qty=$(this).closest('p').find('.qty');

Comment: @MalcolmX `$qty` is just a `element` you can use it simply `qty` but to differentiate that it is a `jquery element`, I `prepend` a `$` before `qty`.

Comment: It is possible to increase by decimal value? like 0.1, 0.2?

Comment: Using `var currentVal = parseInt(qty.val());` raises error **Uncaught TypeError: qty.val is not a function**. Note that I have removed the `$` prepended to the variable. **Why am I getting the error?**

Answer (score 1):

The issue at hand is that the value of `i` is `3` by the time the loop ends. What you want to do is save the value of each iteration so that when the `click` event fires it will still hold the correct value (the value at the time of the event being wired up). One way to do this is with what are called closures. Closures basically close around the value and save the function call with the value used to be called later. One way to accomplish this is with a function factory.

```
function add(value){
    console.log(value);
    var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + value).val());    
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        $("#qty" + value).val(currentVal + 1);
    }
};

function addClosure(value){
    return function(){
        add(value);
    };
};
```

At this point all you need to do is change the click event as follows:

```
$("#add" + i).click(addClosure(i));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infiniteloops/y9huk/

MDN Closures: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Answer (score 0):

in for loop `i` value become `3`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/hMS6Y/1/)**

```
$(function () {

    $("#add1").click(function () {
            add(1);
    });

    $("#minus1").click(function () {
        minus(1);
    });

$("#add2").click(function () {
            add(2);
    });

    $("#minus2").click(function () {
        minus(2);
    });
});

function add(i){
var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + i).val());

        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
            $("#qty" + i).val(currentVal + 1);
        }
}

function minus(i){
  var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + i).val());
        if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
            $("#qty" + i).val(currentVal - 1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code.

```
<body>
    <div id='placeholder'>
    <p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" act='min' id="1" width="20" height="20" />
        <input id="qty1" type="text" value="1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" act='add' id="1" width="20" height="20" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/yOadS1c.png" act='min' id="2" width="20" height="20" />
        <input id="qty2" type="text" value="1">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/98cvZnj.png" act='add' id="2" width="20" height="20" />
    </p>
    </div>
</body>



$(function () {
        $('#placeholder img').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){

            $action = $(this).attr('act');        
            $id = $(this).attr('id');
            $val = parseInt($('#qty'+$id).val());

            if($action == 'add'){
                $val = $val + 1;
            } else {
                if($val > 0){
                    $val = $val - 1;    
                }
            }
            $('#qty'+$id).val($val);

            });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box-qty">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-minus">-</a>
<input type="text" name="p_quantity" id="qnt" class="quantity" value="1">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="quantity-plus">+</a>
</div>

<script>
$(".quantity-plus").click(function(){     
 $("#qnt").val(Number($("#qnt").val())+1);
});

$(".quantity-minus").click(function(){
 if($("#qnt").val()>1)
 $("#qnt").val(Number($("#qnt").val())-1);     
});
<script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your variable i is global in the case it will actually work for #add3, #minus3. Here in code you can try this thing-

```
$(function () {
    var numButtons = 2;
    //console.log(typeof(numButtons));
    //console.log(numButtons);
    for (var i = 1; i <= numButtons; i++) {
        var t = i; //Now t is local 
        $("#add" + t).click(function () {
            console.log(t);
            var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + t).val());
            //console.log(currentVal);
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                $("#qty" + t).val(currentVal + 1);
            }
        });

        $("#minus" + t).click(function () {
            var currentVal = parseInt($("#qty" + t).val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
                $("#qty" + t).val(currentVal - 1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is not going to work. Your variable "t" will still access the value of "i" and end up being 3 because of run time binding.